# vi <TAB> completes only directories in bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete, vi

In a directory I type `vi` and then <kbd>tab</kbd> (twice), this gives me

```
user$ vi 
CMakeFiles/ global/     libs/
```

whereas `ls` followed by 2 <kbd>tab</kbd>s gives me

```
user$ ls 
! core.log CMakeFiles/ global/     libs/ _jni/
```

(Note: **ls is aliased to `ls -Ah --color=auto'**, _jni is a symlink, and none of the files are hidden.)

I think `vi` is not showing any files, but only directories during tab-completion. Why is this happening? How to make `vi` behave same way as `ls`? I put following line in ~/.vimrc after going through one of the posts on SE. But it doesn't seem to do anything in this case.

```
set wildmode=longest,list,full
set wildmenu
```

Version of `vi`: VIM - Vi IMproved version 7.3.429
Version of `ls`: ls (GNU coreutils) 8.13

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem on Arch Linux, and finally I found that was the completion function's problem.

use `complete -r vim` to remove the completer. (or put that line to your bashrc)

Comment: Thanks! `complete -r vi` did it for me.

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is not directly related to the ls command or the vi binary. It is, instead, controlled by the tab completion function of your shell. If you're using bash on linux, you've probably got `/etc/bash_completion` and `/etc/bash_completion.d/*` full of rules for how to implement completion.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean I should ideally put the line `complete -r vi` in `/etc/bash_completion`? Also what does -r (or other options) mean. Both `man complete` and `complete --help` don't seem to tell this.

Comment: @user13107 bash builtins are hard to find good documentation for. What you probably want to do is get rid of /etc/bash_completion.d/vi or some file similar to that

Comment: @user13107 Since `complete` is a bash built-in, use `help complete` or search for it in the SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS section in `man bash`. The latter one is usually more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Check that line similar to below is present in your file `/etc/bash_completion`:

```
complete -f -X '*.@(o|so|so.!(conf)|a|[rs]pm|gif|jp?(e)g|mp3|mp?(e)g|avi|asf|ogg|class)' vi vim gvim rvim view rview rgvim rgview gview emacs xemacs sxemacs kate kwrite
```

Execute this command on shell. Alternatively add above line in the file `/etc/bash_completion` and execute:

```
bash /etc/bash_completion
```